# MySQL distinct and average

Tags: mysql

The following structure is how to envision this query.

```
user_info
    - id int(11)
    - email varchar(255)
    - regdate int(11)

statistics
    - id int(11)
    - playerid int(11)
    - timetopay int(11)
```

All I want to do is get all unique emails from user_info then get the average of statistics.timetopay-user_info.regdate but in the same query.

```
SELECT AVG(s.timetopay-ui.regdate) as time_amount FROM user_info ui    
LEFT JOIN statistics s ON ui.id=s.playerid 
WHERE s.timetopay>'0' GROUP BY ui.email ORDER BY ui.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Hopefully from the above snippet you'll get the gist. I'm just trying to work out the average time it takes a user to pay some money but only if they have.

The above query does not quite work for me at the moment.

I'm having to use group by ui.email as users can have more than one account. Anyone know how I can achieve this in one query?

Comment: "*Hopefully from the above snippet you'll get the gist.*" - Afraid not, no.  Schema and/or sample data would help.  So would the desired resultset for that sample data.  Perhaps upload some test data to http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: I didn't think it was too hard to understand. Let me add some more info.

Comment: It's often difficult to appreciate how little context someone coming to a problem fresh actually has; what might seem obvious to a person who's working with that database day-in & day-out may be completely unintuitive to anyone else.  I'm looking at that query and struggling to understand what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish.  Whilst I might just be a bit slow, a little extra context never goes amiss.  :)

Comment: Try now. Added minimal but a little more extra info :)

Comment: Well, without sample data my only thought is that the effect of the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses are to return `time_amount` only for the user with the greatest `ui.id` who has at least one statistic with `timetopay>0`.  Is this what you had intended?

Comment: You are correct, I was trying to avoid a sub query but i'm not sure it's going to be avoidable.

Comment: It might well be avoidable, if only I had the faintest idea what it is you were trying to accomplish.  Some **sample data** and **your desired resultset for that sample data** would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select avg(daystakenavg) from (
  select avg(s.timetopay - u.regdate) as daystakenavg
  from user_info u
  join statistics s on (u.id = s.playerid)
  group by email
) t
```

Note if the user hasn't made in purchase it will not be displayed in the results. If you want it to then change it to a left join and add a `coalesce` to default to whatever value you want:

```
select avg(daystakenavg) totaldaystakenavg from (
  select coalesce(avg(s.timetopay - u.regdate), 0) as daystakenavg
  from user_info u
  left join statistics s on (u.id = s.playerid)
  group by email
) t
```

Additionally, I wouldn't recommend to use ints as dates... there is a Date data type you should be using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i'm looking for this to return only one row with the avg value only.

Comment: I edited it slightly and think it might be coming out about right now -

Comment: select avg(daystakenavg) from (
  select avg(s.timetopay - u.regdate) as daystakenavg
  from user_info u
  join statistics s on (u.id = s.playerid)
  where s.timetopay>0
  group by email
) t

Comment: Ok I take that back - Average time to pay = 595H 15M 21S

Comment: Seems to be working in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3287/1). Probably you're missing something in the explanation of the fields.

Comment: Yeah seems right in the fiddle, i'll have another look through it in a sec.